# Java library for getting Color from name of color

Tags: java, colors

java.awt.Color has a couple of defined Colors - for example, Color.RED (or Color.red) is a public static value that returns `Color(255, 0, 0)`. But there are only a limited set of colors defined - 13 by my count.

Are there any Java libraries that have the HTML Color Chart colors defined, so I can say something like ColorLibrary.AQUAMARINE and get back #60CC93? Or, even better, are there libraries that map the name to the color, so I can say `Color color = ColorMap.get("aquamarine");`?

Comment: I don't know of a library, but you can simply implement your own helper using these tables: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names

Comment: I see that it could be a nice thing to have in your program, but are you **really** needing it over a few colors hardcoded as `static`s in your program? If you can show a specific usecase, I'd love to hear the idea.

Comment: The Color class from JavaFX contains many more colors. You could load them with reflections.

Comment: As a tip - you could make your life a lot easier if you implement it as an "enhanced" enum class - make the color value a field, then you can use the built-in `ColorEnum.valueOf(String value)` method

Comment: Someone (Adrian Ber) did the work: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/HTMLcolornames.htm
Disclaimer: I don't know if that code is licensed.

Comment: Specific use case: I'm writing a text-based UI that lets people say things like, "color {this data} brown" or "color {this data} light blue", and it knows what to do. Granted, I probably don't expect users to say, "color {this data} lavender bush", but I thought I'd be complete :)

Comment: @David That's a fair use case then indeed.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many libraries which have compiled a map of colour names to rgb/hex values, however there are a few different libraries which provide functions to get colours which are predefined by java.

See:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Convertsagivenstringintoacolor.htm

http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/doc/javadoc/com/martiansoftware/jsap/stringparsers/ColorStringParser.html