# getting a color by name in java

Tags: java, colors

I am working with an object model that contains a `Color` object.

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class MyObject {

    ...
    private String color;

    public void setColor( Color c ) ...
    public Color getColor() ...
    ...

}
```

In the response of a json query, I am left with a physical name of a color

> "color":"blue"

I know that the *Color* object has statics i.e.

```
Color.blue;
```

Is there any way to decode actual color names into Color objects? Or would I need to manually map the strings to rgb values myself?

I am looking for something that should be the output of this

```
Color c = new Color("blue");
```

which does not work

Comment: Where do these colors come from? Do they correspond to Java's constants?

Comment: for arguments sake, yes, there will be no color that does not match what _Color_ has for statics.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21762987/1737819

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your names correspond to those of Java's constants, you can use reflection to map them:

```
public static Color getColorByName(String name) {
    try {
        return (Color)Color.class.getField(name.toUpperCase()).get(null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this:

```
try {
        Class color=Class.forName("android.graphics.Color");
        Field field=color.getField("BLUE");
        int blue=field.getInt(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry if I was uncler, the final output needs to be of a Color object. I thought of using _class.forName_ but was unsure how here.

Comment: Nothing in the question suggest Android. I'd swap `android.graphics` for `java.awt`. Also, as OP wants the object. I'd use `Color blue = field.get(null);`.

Comment: In java:
try {
   Class color=Class.forName("java.awt.Color");
   Field field=color.getField("blue");
   Color blue=(Color) field.get(null);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }